# Using CASE inside conditional IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have the failing statement:

```
select 
    value_1, value_2
from 
    zt_Report
where 
    Division_CD in CASE WHEN @Division ='(ALL EPCD)' THEN ('Epoxy', 'MDP', 'OTG', 'PSR') ELSE @Division END 
    and [Business_CD] like CASE WHEN @Business='(All)' THEN '%' ELSE @Business END 
    and [Plant_TX] like CASE WHEN @Plant='(All)' THEN '%' ELSE @Plant+'%' END
```

Getting an error on the line:

```
Where Division_CD in CASE WHEN @Division ='(ALL EPCD)' THEN ('Epoxy', 'MDP', 'OTG', 'PSR') ELSE @Division END
```

What essentially needs to happen is when the division parameter is passed `(ALL EPCD)`, then the `WHERE` clause will only allow the divisions `'Epoxy', 'MDP', 'OTG', 'PSR'`, otherwise it should filter exactly on that divison, ie. passing `Epoxy` into Division will set the `WHERE` to locate only `Epoxy` division

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not how `case` works.  It returns a scalar value, not a list.  So, you want to do something like this:

```
Where (@Division = '(ALL EPCD)' and Division_CD IN ('Epoxy', 'MDP', 'OTG', 'PSR') or 
       Division_CD = @Division
      ) and 
      (@Business = '(All)' or Business_CD = @Business) and
      (@Plant = '(All)' or Plant_TX like @Plant + '%')
```

Your logic is mixing equality, `like`, and `case` in very strange (and incompatible) ways.

Comment: This works, but I do not understand why. The division part makes sense, but for business, passing `(All)`, the left is true: `@Business = '(All)' ` so it then simply ignores the right, `Business_CD = @Business`, allowing all businesses in?

Comment: @Sauron . . . Yes, that is how the boolean operations work.